# Views page list of all content grouped by taxonomy term

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I have created a view in Drupal 7 that displays all nodes that contain a particular taxonomy vocabulary. The view contains a page in an unformatted list format set to show content | teaser. All I am trying to do is to group the list by the specific taxonomy term. Here is an example of what I'm talking about:

**TERM A**
Title
Teaser

Title
Teaser

**TERM B**
Title
Teaser

I've scoured the web and have only found solutions for displaying EITHER taxonomy terms OR content, but not both. Am I missing something? Is this not possible with Views?

Thank you so much to whomever can help, I've been agonizing over this for days.

-Dave

Comment: Belong these terms to one vocabulary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a view: Show `Content`
2. Add a **Relationship**:

   - *Content: Taxonomy terms on node* (don't check vocabularies) [Identifier: `term`]
3. Add a **Contextual filter**:

   - *Taxonomy vocabulary: Vocabulary ID*:

     - Provide value from URL -> Path component: `2`
4. Add **Fields**, e.g.:

   - *Taxonomy term: Name* which uses the *Relationship* `term`

     - Check: *Exclude form display* and *Link this field to its taxonomy term page* if you like
   - *Content: Rendered Content*:

     - Display -> Show complete entity
     - View mode -> Teaser
5. Define **Format**:

   - e.g. Unformatted list, go to Settings and set for *Grouping field Nr. 1* -> *(term) Taxonomy term: Name*

If you don't like/want to use *fields* as view display rows you can choose Content or Rendered Entity and check 'Force using fields' on Format options do group nodes by taxonomy term.

Now, you can create a page where the path is `vocabulary/%` (or something like that), so the contextual argument we have set in step 3 (path component = `2`) will be now passed to the view as a Vocabulary ID (`vid`). You can also define an alias for path `vocabulary/$vid` (vocabulary/2 => cars).

---

This is the exported view:

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'nodes_terms_vocabulary';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->human_name = 'Nodes and Terms by Vocabulary';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '50';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['offset'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['id'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['quantity'] = '9';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['grouping'] = array(
  0 => array(
    'field' => 'name',
    'rendered' => 1,
    'rendered_strip' => 0,
  ),
);
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['default_row_class'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['row_class_special'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['uses_fields'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'node';
/* Relationship: Content: Taxonomy terms on node */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['term_node_tid']['id'] = 'term_node_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['term_node_tid']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['term_node_tid']['field'] = 'term_node_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['term_node_tid']['vocabularies'] = array(
  'section_ytic' => 0,
  'section_apti' => 0,
  'language' => 0,
  'newsletter' => 0,
  'tags' => 0,
  'subjects' => 0,
  'translation_mode_type' => 0,
  'internal' => 0,
  'resources' => 0,
);
/* Field: Excluded: Taxonomy term: Name */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['id'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['table'] = 'taxonomy_term_data';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['relationship'] = 'term_node_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['ui_name'] = 'Excluded: Taxonomy term: Name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
/* Sort criterion: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['title']['field'] = 'title';
/* Contextual filter: Taxonomy vocabulary: Vocabulary ID */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['vid']['id'] = 'vid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['vid']['table'] = 'taxonomy_vocabulary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['vid']['field'] = 'vid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['vid']['relationship'] = 'term_node_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['vid']['default_action'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['vid']['default_argument_type'] = 'raw';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['vid']['default_argument_options']['index'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['vid']['summary']['number_of_records'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['vid']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['vid']['summary_options']['items_per_page'] = '25';
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'nodes_terms_vocabulary_page');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'vocabulary/%';
```

Comment: Thank you LaTradia, I will definitely give this a shot! So much appreciate your help -Dave

Comment: Hi, This displays all the terms and the nodes that are grouped under terms. For example, if I am viewing a taxonomy **Term1** page, is there a way to display the term grouped nodes that are common for the  **Term1** and other terms for those nodes.

Comment: Can I add a filter for this bsaed on the url to filter out all the related content?

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you would go about doing this:

1. Include the tag you want to group by in your fields (see map)
2. Click on your format settings. (see map)
3. Set grouping field to the tag.
4. Set exclude from display to true in your tag field.

That should get you to where you want to be.

Here's a map of where 1 and 2 would be located.

[image: Here's a map to help]

Comment: Jance, really appreciate the resopnse! I'll give LaTradia and your suggestion a try, hopefully that'll do the trick! Really appreciate your help. -Dave